# Maven multi module dependency issue

Tags: java, maven

I have a problem where I have a main project pom. This specifies the two main modules of the application. This main pom contains some common dependency definitions:

**Parent:**

```
<groupId>com.maven.showcase</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<modules>
    <module>main.module.1</module>
    <module>main.module.2</module>
</modules>

<properties>
    <main.module.1.version>1.1.1-SNAPSHOT</main.module.1.version>
    <main.module.2.version>2.2.2-SNAPSHOT</main.module.2.version>
</properties>
```

The versions of the two main modules are defined here. The version of each main module and all sub modules within that module are the same. I've the ${revision} property to achieve this.

**Main pom 1:**

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.maven.showcase</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>main.module.1</artifactId>
<version>${revision}</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
    <revision>${main.module.1.version}</revision>
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>sub.module.1</module>
</modules>
```

**Main pom 2:**

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.maven.showcase</groupId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>main.module.2</artifactId>
<version>${revision}</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
    <revision>${main.module.2.version}</revision>
</properties>

<modules>
    <module>sub.module.2</module>
</modules>
```

Each module contains a single sub module.

**Sub module 1:**

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>main.module.1</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.maven.showcase</groupId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
</parent>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>sub.module.1</artifactId>
```

**Sub module 2:**

```
<parent>
    <artifactId>main.module.2</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.maven.showcase</groupId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
</parent>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<artifactId>sub.module.2</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>sub.module.1</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.maven.showcase</groupId>
        <version>${main.module.1.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

As you can see sub module 2 references sub module 1 as a dependency. The is the one defined in the main pom. This works well when I build the entire project. There is a problem though when I attempt to build sub module 2:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project sub.module.2: Could not
>   resolve dependencies for project
>   com.maven.showcase:sub.module.2:jar:2.2.2-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect
>   dependencies at com.maven.showcase:sub.module.1:jar:1.1.1-SNAPSHOT:
>   Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   com.maven.showcase:sub.module.1:jar:1.1.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find
>   artifact com.maven.showcase:main.module.1:pom:${revision} in central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]

I can totally understand why this happens, as when I only build sub module 2, main module's pom never actually gets parsed so maven would not know what to put in the place of "revision".

Question is: Is there a better way to approach this issue? I can't get global properties to work as I am constantly getting "Properties are prohibited in parent pom definition" if I try to use the properties I defined in the parent pom. (Maven 3.5.3)

I need to be able to build separate sub modules for various reasons, for example to get the maven dependency tree.

Thanks,
PeTer

Comment: First I strongly recommend to read https://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html furthermore the properties for each modules versions does not makes sense for a multi module build. If you want to define a intermodule dependency just use `${project.version}`...

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT use placeholders for version numbers! The version is key for maven and should not be made abstract.

Please check the "mvn versions:set" plugin. It will help you in case you have to change version numbers. It will automatically change it in all the neccessary places. You should not feel the need for placeholders anymore with this. ;)